# Rails 4 - if @model.save cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I write this if/unless statement, so that it looks for IF this **and** UNLESS that?

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @request.save
    if @request.product.require_approval      ## UNLESS @request.project ##
      do stuff...
    else
      do other stuff...
    end
  else
        format.html { render action: 'new', notice: 'There was an error with your request.' }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: unless is a negation of if so why not `if @request.product.require_approval && !@request.project` ?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.  Would you like to put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You have already accepted another identical response so it would be pointless ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can combined the two. For your example I think the solution that is most clear would be stick with an `if`:

`if @request.product.require_approval && !@request.project`

There are some articles you can find online that specifically suggest avoiding chaining conditions together with `unless`, which is why I think you should stay with an `if`:

- http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/12/01/unless-the-abused-ruby-conditional/
- http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2699-making-sense-with-rubys-unless

Comment: Combining works - thanks!  I'll look into those articles for future use.  I will accept your answer when it allows me to.  :) Thanks.